# Combine control content and html on ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm after a bit of help getting the correct syntax to add controls to a WebForm or if it's not possible how do I do this.

Webform1.aspx contains headers and navbar with css applied. Default.aspx contains a page with controls. I want Default.aspx to look the same as Webform1.aspx so it has the same headers, navbar and css.

Most of my attempts result in an error `Parser Error Message: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.`

Current code is as follows:

**Webform1.aspx:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/newtheme/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <!-- other Css -->
<script>
    <!-- scripts -->
</script>
</head>
<body id="page1">
    <div id="main_outer">
      <div id="main"> 
        <!-- header -->
        <header>
        <div class="inside">
            <div class="extra-wrap">
              <h1><a>Header</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <!-- navigation -->
        </nav>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Welcome" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/members/themes/default/default.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    Inherits="members_Default" 
    Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>
<%@ Register Src="/members/controls/membership-info.ascx" TagName="membership" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" 
    ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" 
    ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
        <uc1:membership ID="membership" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Why is `WebForm1.aspx` not your master page?

Comment: Because the master page is a different layout.

Comment: It looks like you need a master page, a different one matching WebForm1.aspx

Comment: Why don't you make it a second master page? You can have more than one, and master pages that inherit master pages, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a Content control to your Webform1.aspx, then assign the Default.aspx as the content of the new Content control.
This will effectively make the Webform1 a master page for your Default page, and you'll have to set that as Master page in the Page directive of Default.
You'll have to change the Webform1 to a master page, as suggested in comments, so you'll have to decide if you'll be using that currently-assigned master page or not, and assign it as master for the Webform1 if you do.
Multiple master pages are not uncommon at all.